# Access to existing fields in a large C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to add a new functionality (say my_work.c) to a large open-source project. For that I need to access few fields whose declarations and definitions are spread across the existing code base.

I cannot "include (path to header file)" for all fields as the number of include statements will be massive . How do I get access to all the fields without a bunch of includes. I think I can get this access by adding my function my_work.c in the Makefile but I'm unaware of where do I need to include this ?

Comment: Your question as it's worded is kind of confusing. Contrary to what you said here, you **are** going to have to use `#include`'s and use the -I flag when compiling.

Comment: If you want to access a field in a structure, you need access to definition of the structure, which means #including the header that contains it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if there large number of structures that I need access to, is there a way to bypass the need to have include headers ?

Comment: " is there a way to bypass the need to have include headers" - no.

Comment: @kris No. Why would headers exist in the first place otherwise?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to accomplish what you are asking for without including the header files. If your my_work source file ends up needing a "massive" amount includes, perhaps this can be an indication that you should consider breaking up your new file into smaller ones. Moreover, if a large amount of includes really bothers you, double check to see if there is a single header file for the project that includes all or almost all other header files. Here's an example that comes to mind https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Box2D/Box2D.h

Comment: thanks all, I think I'll follow the answer from @diametralpitch. Create one header file (exhaustive_header.h) that includes all header files throughout the whole project and then use this in my file.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get access to all the fields without a bunch of includes.

You don't. That's what includes are for: getting access to external code.

However, some compilers, e.g. Clang and GCC, support a flag which can be used to insert implicit `#include`s:

From `man clang`:

```
   -include <filename>
          Adds  an implicit #include into the predefines buffer which is read
          before the source file is preprocessed.
```

From `man gcc`:

```
   -include file
       Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of the
       primary source file.  However, the first directory searched for file
       is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory
       containing the main source file.  If not found there, it is searched
       for in the remainder of the "#include "..."" search chain as normal.

       If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in the
       order they appear on the command line.
```

Note that this method is still going to include those files so you'd better do it the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

If C++ is well-written, every include can be included on its own. It includes everything it depends on to compile. Now it's unlikely your data is genuinely spread out over a massive codebase at random. Try to #include the higher level objects. With any luck, that will pull in most of the lower level ones. If the compilation breaks, suggest moving to a "one include" policy for the long term.